# Constructing Symbolic Functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to build a symbolic function in Matlab, as follows:

```
syms theta
Rx(theta) = cos(theta) + sin(theta);
```

When I enter `Rx(0.1)`, Matlab returns `cos(1/10) + sin(1/10)`

But what I'm trying to do is get Matlab to evaluate it numerically. I can accomplish that with `double(Rx(0.1))`, but when doing the same thing on much more complex functions in a loop, the conversion to double each time causes it to run very slowly. Is there a way to alter `Rx` itself to give numeric output?

Comment: If you need numeric output, just avoid the Symbolic Toolbox entirely. `Rx = @(theta) cos(theta) + sin(theta);` should be just as effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a standard (non-symbolic), anonymous function from your symbolic function. For this you use [`matlabFunction`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html)

```
syms theta
Rx(theta) = cos(theta) + sin(theta);
Rxd = matlabFunction(Rx);
```

Then

```
>> Rxd(0.1)
ans =
   1.094837581924854
```

Note that *you may lose precision*, though, as the computations are done numerically from the beginning, as opposed to symbolically and converted to `double` only at the end.